# Parse error in my shell-script

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting

I am having trouble to run this code, Anyone have a thought

```
#! /bin/bash
while :
do
   echo "Enter file name along with absolute path : "
   read -r inputFile
   echo "Enter path you would like to save copy of the file : "
   read  -r pathinput
   path=$pathinput


if ((-f "$inputFile" ; -d "$pathinput" ))
then
    cp -p $inputFile $path
    break
else
    echo "File does not exist. Try again."
fi
done
echo  " Job Done"
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things catch my attention:

- `if ((-f "$inputFile" ; -d "$pathinput" ))` seems a mix between bash arithmetic and tests. What you are trying to do is : `if [[ -f $inputFile && -d $pathinput ]]`
- `cp -p $inputFile $path` VS `cp -p "$inputFile" "$path"` Use more quotes !

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
>   http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
>   http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
>   http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Think of using https://www.shellcheck.net/ at a first glance when you have a shell issue